# Google Chrome Crash on Startup

Tags: google-chrome, crash

I prefer to use Safari but I'm going into web design so I want to have a few browsers on my MacBook to view my work. When I try and open Chrome, it crashes on startup. This has been a problem since I upgraded to Mountain Lion. I have tried removing the application support and libraries and uninstalling but nothing has fixed this issue. Is their a fix for this crash? This crash is making Chrome unusable.

Comment: Have you reinstalled Chrome? (probably a new version by now)

Comment: Could you create a new user account on the Mac and try to launch Google Chrome from there ?
It will help to determine if the issue is within your usual user account or system-wide.

Comment: I had an issue where Chrome crashed whenever I tried to install an extension (even after I deleted support files and reinstalled it), but it started working normally after I did an upgrade install of OS X from the recovery partition. If you don't want to do that, the 10.9 upgrade might fix it.

Comment: @PEM8000 I enabled the Guest account. It still crashes on a different user account.

Comment: this is happening to me as well... and removing the app and reinstalling doesn't work either